# fread returns string but only consists of number?

Tags: php, fread

I am pretty new to PHP. At the moment I'm trying to implement it on my weather site.

My weather station software reads data and uploads a .txt file to my FTP which consists of a number like 22.3 , always a dot and always one decimal.

In my index.php I read this file using the following code:

```
    <?php
    $temp_nu = fopen("data/temp_nu.txt", "r") or die("Data saknas, temp.nu.txt"); 
    echo fread($temp_nu, filesize("data/temp_nu.txt"));
    fclose($temp_nu); 
    ?>
```

Now this part is working just fine, but I want to be able to change the font colour depending on the temperature. So I'm seeking something like:

```
    if ($temp_nu1 > 20) {
        echo "<p style=color:'red'>", $temp_nu1, "</p>";
    } else {
        echo $temp_nu1;
    }
```

However this is not working, in fact I've come to realize that PHP treats my variable as a string, which I thought it wouldn't since I've read so much about PHP being a "loose data type langauge". I've tried several times converting this into a float or int but without success.

Any help would be greatly appriciated!
Thanks in advance,

PS. The text file can be viewed here: http://retzner.se/anders/vader/lund/data/temp_nu.txt . DS

Comment: If `$temp_nu1` is a string with a number in it this should work. WHat does `var_dump($temp_nu1)` show just before the if statement?

Comment: Also how are you getting the `$temp_nu1` variable?

Comment: var_dump returns
string(5) "21.8 "

Comment: I'm getting $temp_nu1 by $temp_nu1 = fread($temp_nu, filesize("data/temp_nu.txt"));

Comment: Well, `"21.8 " > 20`, so you *should* see `<p style="color:red">21.8 </p>`.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it works fine. I made a mistake in the echo "<p style>"

Comment: Also, loose data type doesn't mean php will automatically convert a string into a number for you. It just means some casting will be done based on the operator that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$temp_nu1 = trim(file_get_contents("data/temp_nu.txt"));
```

I guess you have newline in the file.

Comment: Is it string(4) or string(5)?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my echo "<p style>"

Comment: It should be <p style="color:red;">

Answer (score 0):

You may need to typecast values:- give it a try.

```
if (floatval($temp_nu1) > floatval(20)) {
    echo "<p style='color:red'> $temp_nu1 </p>";
 } else {
    echo $temp_nu1;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the safest way. Though my problem was in the <p style>, It should be written as <p style ="color:red;">. Thanks for the input tho.